# ANTLR is omitting some rules

Tags: java, antlr

I have the next grammar for the language PSeint (Doc:http://pseint.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=pseudocodigo.php):

```
grammar expr;


prog: ((expr|asignacion|llamadafunc|leer|escribir) '\r\n')*;
escribir: ESCRIBIR expr (',' expr)*;
leer: LEER VARIABLE (',' VARIABLE)*;
asignacion: (VARIABLE|array) ASIGNACION expr;

expr:expr operadores expr
    |   (array|numerico|string|bool|VARIABLE);
    

array: (VARIABLE CI (r_int|VARIABLE | llamadafunc) (',' (r_int|VARIABLE | llamadafunc))* CF);

llamadafunc:VARIABLE PI ((expr|llamadafunc) (',' ((expr|llamadafunc) ))*)? PF;


operadores: MOD
    |   POT
    |   OPSUP
    |   OPINF
    |   COMPARADORES
    |   NO
    |   OPBOOL
    ;

r_int: PI r_int PF
    | r_int MOD r_int
    |   r_int POT r_int
    |   r_int OPSUP r_int
    |   r_int OPINF r_int
    |   INT
    ;

real: PI real PF
    |   real POT real
    |   real OPSUP real
    |   real OPINF real
    |   FLOAT
    ;

numerico: real | r_int;

string: PI CADENA PF
    | CADENA
    ;

bool:PI bool PF
    |   bool COMPARADORES bool
    |   bool OPBOOL bool
    |   numerico COMPARADORES numerico
    |   CADENA COMPARADORES CADENA
    |   BOOL
    ;


RESERVADAS:DIMENSION
    |   FINTOTAL
    |   ESCRIBIR
    |   SINO
    |   HACER
    |   PARA
    |   PROCESO
    |   LEER
    |   SI
    |   HASTA
    |   QUE
    |   CON
    |   PASO
    |   DE
    |   OTRO
    |   MIENTRAS
    |   REPETIR
    |   SEGUN
    |   DEFINIR
    |   FUNCION
    |   ALGORITMO
    |   TIPOS
    |   MOD
    |   NO
    |   AND
    |   OR
    ;


TIPOS: (ENTERO|CARACTER|LOGICO|REAL);
fragment ENTERO: E N T E R O;
fragment  CARACTER: C A R A C T E R ;
fragment LOGICO: L O G I C O;
fragment REAL: R E A L;
FINTOTAL: FIN (PARA|PROCESO|SI|MIENTRAS|SEGUN|FUNCION|ALGORITMO)*;
ESCRIBIR: E S C R I B I R;
DIMENSION: D I M E N S I O N;
SINO: S I N O;
HACER: H A C E R;
PARA: P A R A;
PROCESO: P R O C E S O;
LEER: L E E R;
FIN: F I N;
SI: S I;
HASTA: H A S T A;
QUE: Q U E;
CON: C O N;
PASO: P A S O;
DE: D E;
OTRO: O T R O;
MIENTRAS: M I E N T R A S;
REPETIR: R E P E T I R;
SEGUN: S E G U N;
DEFINIR: D E F I N I R;
FUNCION: F U N C I O N ;
ALGORITMO:A L G O R I T M O;
fragment A:[aA];
fragment B:[bB];
fragment C:[cC];
fragment D:[dD];
fragment E:[eE];
fragment F:[fF];
fragment G:[gG];
fragment H:[hH];
fragment I:[iI];
fragment J:[jJ];
fragment K:[kK];
fragment L:[lL];
fragment M:[mM];
fragment N:[nN];
fragment O:[oO];
fragment P:[pP];
fragment Q:[qQ];
fragment R:[rR];
fragment S:[sS];
fragment T:[tT];
fragment U:[uU];
fragment V:[vV];
fragment W:[wW];
fragment X:[xX];
fragment Y:[yY];
fragment Z:[zZ];



VARIABLE: LETRA (LETRA|DIGITO)*;
INT: DIGITO+;
FLOAT: DIGITO* '.' DIGITO*;
BOOL: ('Falso' | 'Verdadero');

CADENA: (CS|CD) (ESC|.)*? (CS|CD) ;
fragment CS: ['] ;
fragment CD: '"';
fragment ESC: '\\'[btnr]'\\' ;


MOD: '%'|(M O D);
POT: '^';
OPSUP:(PRODUCTO|DIVISION);
fragment PRODUCTO:'*';
fragment DIVISION:'/';
OPINF:(SUMA|RESTA);
fragment SUMA:'+';
fragment RESTA:'-';

COMPARADORES:(MAYOR|MENOR|MAYIGUAL|MENIGUAL|IGUAL|DISTINTO);
fragment MAYOR:'>';
fragment MENOR:'<';
fragment MAYIGUAL:'>=';
fragment MENIGUAL:'<=';
fragment IGUAL:'==';
fragment DISTINTO:'!=';

NO: '~'|(N O);
OPBOOL: AND | OR;
fragment AND: '&'|(A N D);
fragment OR: '|'|(O R);



ASIGNACION:(FLECHA|IG);
fragment FLECHA:'<-';
fragment IG:'=';

COMENTARIO_LINEA: '//' .*? '\n' ->skip;
COMENTARIO_MULTILINEA: '/*' .*? '*/' ->skip;
CI:'[';
CF:']';
PI:'(';
PF:')';
LETRA: [a-zA-Z];
DIGITO:[0-9];
WS: (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r'|';')+ -> skip;
```

but when I try to run grun and recognize a line like Leer a,b,c or escribi d[],x I always get just the rule prog. It should be recognizing the rules just as it does with expr or llamadafunc, but does not, why is it?
[Picture showing the AST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGwWL.png)

Comment: Missing EOF at the end of `prog: ((expr|...) '\r\n')* EOF ;`

Comment: Please give more input examples, I have found other errors.